# remove A HREF inheritence in Div

Tags: html

I am trying to remove the inheritance of the href that appears to have been caused by the nested div.

The external CSS i am using has no mention of a:href or anything, and when i reorder the div to make the href one the last nested div, it doesnt inherit (because it's last).
Can someone please tel lme if there is a way in html to remove the inheritence as i need it in this order.
Thanks

```
  <div id = "logo">
     <a href="index.php"><img src="./images/logo.jpg" alt="logo image">
  </div>

  <div id = "scrolltext">
     <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</marquee>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try closing the `a` like `</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<div id = "logo">
     <a href="index.php"><img src="./images/logo.jpg" title="logo image"> Link </a>
  </div>

  <div id = "scrolltext">
     <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</marquee>
  </div>
```

Comment: Added closing <a> tag and changed "alt" to "title" in <img> tag

Comment: Please give description

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik I'm sorry but description on what?

Comment: wow, whoops. Can't believe I overlooked the unclosed tag. Thanks all.